# Pandas pivot_table not grouping index values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pivot table which shows the development of Reserves on a month to month basis. The problem I am having is when I create the pivot table using pandas it is creating separate line items for the same claim number.

The code below shows the desired output, while the table below shows what my actual data is giving me.

Pay specific attention to Claim Number 200932768. It should show the Reserve of 200000 for both Feb and March side by side.

```
data={'Claim Number':[200932768,102349182,200943556,200932768,300943556,400943556],'Reserve':[200000,50000,0,200000,5000,0],'Key':['Feb','Feb','Feb','March','March','March']}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    table=df.pivot_table(index='Claim Number',columns='Key',values='Reserve')
```

I have tried maybe changing the 'Claim Number' Field from dtype object to int, but the same issue persist. For context in the original data file we are given two spread sheets of data. One for the month of Feb, and one for March. I imported both of those sheets as CSV, and concatenated the tables before creating the pivot table.

```
              Reserve
Key          Feb  March
Claim Number|
----------- |------|
102349182   |50000 | NaN
200932768   |200000| NaN
200943556   |0     | NaN
300943556   |NaN   | 5000
400943556   |NaN   | 0
200932768   |NaN   |200000
```

Comment: What pandas version are you using? This works for me.

Comment: Using the dummy data works for me also.

Comment: check `df['Claim Number'].values` to make sure they are indeed the same: no leading or trailing spaces

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was the issue. The Feb data was dtype string, while March was object. Cheers.